# fullcalendar'' has no exported member 'Options'.- getting error in Angular

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm following this [ApNg2Fullcalendar](https://github.com/lbertenasco/ap-ng2-fullcalendar-demo) installing structure step by step , Im used Angular 5 ,

but I had following error
[image]

> node_modules/ap-angular2-fullcalendar/src/calendar/calendar.d.ts(3,10):
>   error TS2305: Module ''fullcalendar'' has no exported member
>   'Options'. node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(695,36):
>   error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(696,29): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(697,20): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(759,22): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(775,50): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(988,23): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryEventObject'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(1401,70): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryAjaxSettings'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(1603,50): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(1623,50): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.
>   node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.d.ts(2588,50): error
>   TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryPromise'.

how to fix it?
my **index.component.ts**

```
import { Component,  } from '@angular/core';
import 'Fullcalendar';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
})
export class IndexComponent  {
  title = 'app';

  calendarOptions:Object = {
    height: 'parent',
    fixedWeekCount : false,
    defaultDate: '2016-09-12',
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
    events: [
      {
        title: 'All Day Event',
        start: '2016-09-01'
      },
      {
        title: 'Long Event',
        start: '2016-09-07',
        end: '2016-09-10'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2016-09-09T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        id: 999,
        title: 'Repeating Event',
        start: '2016-09-16T16:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2016-09-11',
        end: '2016-09-13'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2016-09-12T10:30:00',
        end: '2016-09-12T12:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Lunch',
        start: '2016-09-12T12:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2016-09-12T14:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Happy Hour',
        start: '2016-09-12T17:30:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Dinner',
        start: '2016-09-12T20:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Birthday Party',
        start: '2016-09-13T07:00:00'
      },
      {
        title: 'Click for Google',
        url: 'http://google.com/',
        start: '2016-09-28'
      }
    ]
  };

  onCalendarInit(initialized: boolean) {
    console.log('Calendar initialized');
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { CalendarComponent } from 'ap-angular2-fullcalendar';
import { CalendarModule } from 'ap-angular2-fullcalendar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    IndexComponent,

    CalendarComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    AngularFontAwesomeModule,

    routes


  ],
```

**index.component.html**

```
<angular2-fullcalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (initialized)="onCalendarInit($event)"></angular2-fullcalendar>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is in fullcalendar package inside ap-angular2-fullcalendar node_modules.
Fullcalendar has been updated **3.8.0** but you need **3.7.0**...
My solution is...

Step 1: `npm install fullcalendar@3.7.0 --save`;

Step 2: in your package.json write/edit '**postinstall**' 
to "*rm -Rf ./node_modules/app-angular2-fullcalendar/node_modules*"

Comment: Thanks sir I'm Installed this `npm install fullcalendar@3.6.1` now its work

Comment: @Ruslan Kovalchuk same thing I do but not working...!

Answer (score 4):

Just do this - you're probably using the Angular CLI:

```
npm i @types/fullcalendar -s
```

You don't have the typings

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem too. I solved it updating fullcalendar dependecie exactly to version 3.6.1.

> npm install --save fullcalendar@3.6.1

Answer (score 2):

After install `npm install fullcalendar@3.7.0 --save`I am getting issue

`Module ''fullcalendar'' has no exported member 'Options'` in angular 8.

Answer (score 1):

I Found some solution now its work for me Im Updated to `npm install fullcalendar@3.6.1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in fullcalendar package version. Follow below commands to install fullcalendar with proper versioning. working fine.

Step 1: npm install ng-fullcalendar --save; // version ^2.0.3

Step 2: npm install @fullcalendar/core@4.0.1 --save;

Step 3: npm install @fullcalendar/daygrid@4.0.1 --save;

Step 4: npm install @fullcalendar/interaction@4.0.1 --save;